# Перенаправление потоков в командном файле (CMD, BAT)

Tags: bat, cmd

Есть некоторая необходимость производить логирование работы программы, при этом не хотелось бы терять возможность отображения данных на экране консоли.

Команда:

```
dir > List.txt
```

произведет запись каталогов и файлов текущей директории в указанный файл. Хотелось бы, чтобы данные также еще отобразились в консоли. Есть возможность наверняка такая, например:

```
dir > list.txt 2>&1
```

но никак не соображу, как можно один поток писать и на экран и в файл.

Comment: Посмотрите, есть ли команда (исполняемый файл) tee. В unix-like'ах она используется для таких фокусов

    ls | tee file >file1

Comment: хоть и поздно, но (для проформы):
"Использование операторов перенаправления команд"
http://www.windowsfaq.ru/content/view/260/57/

Answer (score 4):

Если у вас нет доступа к утилите `tee`, вы можете написать и скомпилировать её сами.

Например, так:

```
/*
  Tee utility by VladD
  Use it in whichever way you like
  Hopefully it doesn't do anything bad, but no warranty
  Compiles with MSVC 2012
*/

#include "stdafx.h" // comment this line out if compiling with non-Microsoft compiler

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

bool append = false;
char** curr_arg;
vector<ostream*> target_streams;
vector<string> stream_names;

bool have_open_error = false;
bool have_io_error = false;

void evaluate_args()
{
    for (; *curr_arg; curr_arg++)
    {
        string arg(*curr_arg);
        if (arg == "--")
        {
            curr_arg++;
            break;
        }
        else if (arg == "-a")
        {
            append = true;
        }
        // add more arguments here
        else if (arg.size() > 0 && arg[0] == '-')
        {
            cerr << "Unknown argument: " << arg << endl;
            exit(1);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

void create_streams()
{
    auto openmode = ios::out | (append ? ios::app : ios::trunc);

    target_streams.push_back(&cout);
    stream_names.push_back("-");

    for (; *curr_arg; curr_arg++)
    {
        string arg(*curr_arg);
        ostream* p;
        if (arg == "-")
        {
            p = &cout;
        }
        else
        {
            p = new ofstream(arg, openmode);
            if (!*p)
            {
                delete p;
                cerr << "Cannot open file `" << arg << "'" << endl;
                have_open_error = true;
                return;
            }
        }
        target_streams.push_back(p);
        stream_names.push_back(arg);
    }
}

void destroy_streams()
{
    for (auto p : target_streams)
    {
        if (p != &cout)
            delete p;
    }
}

void process()
{
    string line;
    while (getline(cin, line))
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < target_streams.size(); i++)
        {
            auto p = target_streams[i];
            if (!p)
                continue;
            (*p) << line << endl;
            if (!*p)
            {
                cerr << "Error occured writing to stream `" <<
                        stream_names[i] << "'" << endl;
                delete p;
                target_streams[i] = nullptr;
                have_io_error = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    curr_arg = argv + 1;
    evaluate_args();

    create_streams();
    process();

    destroy_streams();
    return (have_open_error ? 0x2 : 0) | (have_io_error ? 0x4 : 0);
}
```

Comment: Оригинальная лицензия ))

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Ну так :-)

Answer (score 2):

В shell и его потомках есть утилита [tee](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee), которая как раз предназначена для того, чтобы перенаправлять потоки и одновременно записывать их в файл. `man tee:`

> ```
> tee [ -ai ] [ File ... ]
> ```
>
> The `tee` utility copies standard input to standard output, making a
>   copy in zero or more files.  The output is unbuffered.
>
> The following options are available:
>
> ```
>  -a      Append the output to the files rather than overwriting them.
>
>  -i      Ignore the SIGINT signal.
> ```

Самый простой способ получить к ней доступ — установить [cygwin](https://cygwin.com/), а самый простой способ его установить — через [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/). После этого у вас появится возможность писать скрипты на bash и пользоваться соответствующим набором утилит.

Для одной конкретной задачи это, возможно, слишком сложное решение. Но если необходимость в автоматизации и скриптах возникает часто, то в долгосрочной перспективе это, наверняка, будет оптимальным решением.

Answer (score 0):

**Есть способ, конечно же...и не один.** Самое первое, что мне пришло в голову, так это объединение команд:

```
dir > C:\log.txt && dir
```

Можно также тупо сначала писать логи в файл, а затем сразу же выводить их оттуда, но данный способ основан, опять же на объединении команд( и способ костыльный, имхо ).

Comment: а эта комбинация не означает, что команда dir выполнилась 2 раза?.. 
у меня такое ощущение, что выполняется команда dir, данные записываются в файл, потом выполняется команда dir и данные выводятся на экран...
Просто для утилиты, которая логи будет выводить, это не приемлимо, это ж получается, она отработает минут 20 для записи в лог, а потом еще столько же для вывода на экран =)) тогда уж проще записать в файл, а потом вывести файл на экран =)) но хотелось бы, чтобы информация на экране обновлялась по мере поступления данных.

Answer (score 0):

тут дали пример unix-like, так если скачать UnxUtils с sourceforge, то вполне можно использовать. Там есть команда tee отдельным exe

Answer (score 0):

Вот так:

```
dir >list.txt >&2
```

или

```
dir >list.txt 1>&2
```

Comment: Что-то не работает...

Comment: @Qwertiy Да, ошибочка вышла. Пока получилось только с wintee https://code.google.com/archive/p/wintee/